# Titles that are exceedingly long extend too far into the right and may crowd the poor "Ask Question" button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

See the image. A question with long title made the "Ask Question" appear to be the part of that question!! The "Ask Question" button intrudes inside Question title unintentionally. Please provide it a "space" of fresh air

[image]

Comment: +1 for hand-drawn circle but you missed the opportunity to make a question title on this qeustion that reproduce the same issue on this page :p

Comment: @ivarni No need to change the title, you can just reduce the screen size :)

Comment: Fair point, though that sounds a bit like work :)

Comment: I thought it was a tag in the question title.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kXniTAG.jpg it just needs to Breat, this is what you see when you hide the left menu in the hamburger

Comment: Thanks @AgeDeO for the edit and reproducing the issue in this question.

Comment: @ivarni The edited question by AgeDeO servers the purpose :p

Comment: Y did you edit @yivi the previous question title was fun :)

Comment: I found the "breathe breathe breathe" at the end confusing. At first I thought it was actually defacing the question. When reading the title in the question list it made little to no sense. The edit preserves the intention to demonstrate the problem, but attempting to prerserve meaning as well.

Comment: It actually reproduced the issue that is described in the question :) Well your edit also reproducing it so no issues (y)

Comment: I wish everyone used my resolution so I can responsibly remove _"Ask Question"_ from the title. (the actual button is in the same position for me :P)

Comment: Logically it should be the same width as the post/mainbar - `max-width: calc(100% - 300px - 24px);` on the `h1` should do it. - https://imgur.com/6PbGKzJ

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Unfortunately, there is no possibility to upvote edits. So just let me say that I absolutely love your humour.

Comment: @HermannDöppes Sounds like a feature request. And a necessary one considering the edit chain.

Comment: That button really need to be moved. It looks even worse on mobile.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not sure that limiting it to the mainbar width is appropriate. The top content in the right-sidebar is specifically about the displayed question. Limiting the question title width makes it appear that the right-sidebar information is excluded from being a part of the question. IMO, all that's really needed is a little bit of `margin-left` on the `<div>` containing the button, or on the button itself.

Comment: I don't see a problem here as long as it doesn't overlap with the button. They just use available screen space efficiently.

Comment: This is indeed an amusing happenstance worthy of Twitter or something, but not something to justify a design change. Due to this, I highly suspect the votes are reflecting the "lol score" rather than suggestion's score.

Comment: I tend to disagree @ivan_pozdeev. The new sidebar design changes have raised much complaints already that the space at many places on UI is left unused (see for instance https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=design+space+%5Bbug%5D) And it does not look consistent when some part of UI is using the space "efficiently" while more part of it does not